# Keyboard shortcut for openning ~/Downloads on Linux

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, mint

Is there a way to create custom shortcut to open `~/Downloads` on Linux mint 20? I think Ubuntu mate 20.04 will have similar solution. I tried adding custom shortcut with command `/home/username/Downloads`, it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nemo /home/username/Downloads
```

should be your custom command, if you're using Mint Cinnamon. In Ubuntu it's nautilus (just tested).

Cheers..!!

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu-MATE doesn't use `nautilus`  (that's GNOME's file manager)

Comment: I know, that's Caja in Mate